# How to write a Python async serial async reader?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am porting some C++ code to Python and I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to have an onReceive handler for serial bytes. I am using

```
import serial_asyncio
class Arduino: #comms is with an Arduino in serial mode)
    async def connect(self, serial_port):
        (self.serial_reader, self.serial_writer) = await 
        serial_asyncio.open_serial_connection(url=serial_port, baudrate=115200)
        print("serial opened:", serial_port)
        self.buffer = b""

    async def recv(self, data):
        self.buffer += data
        self.process_buffer(self.buffer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     ardunio = Arduino("/dev/ttyS0")         
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(ardunio.connect())
     loop.run_forever()
```

However I cannot figure out how to patch the recv handler in to the read.
I Qt, I could:

```
connect(&QAbstractSocket::readyRead, &Arduino::handleBytes);
```

In Node:

```
arduino.on('data', line => console.log(line))
```

In Python, there doesn't seem to be any obvious answer? How do I get the serial port bytes that arrive to be passed into Arduino.receive(self, data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I cannot figure out how to patch the recv handler in to the read.

`open_serial_connection` is not a callback-based interface, it returns a pair of *streams* which expose the contents through coroutines. This allows you to communicate with the serial port as if you were writing blocking code, i.e. without the use of callbacks and buffers that build up data. For example (untested):

```
async def main():
    reader, writer = await serial_asyncio.connect(url="/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200)
    # instead of: arduino.on('data', line => console.log(line))
    # ...we can just read some data from the serial port
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    # ...and print it right here
    print(repr(data))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Coroutines like `StreamReader.read` will appear to block waiting for data, but they will really just suspend the current coroutine and let the event loop do other things. This allows you to easily express timeouts or do other processing while waiting for the data to arrive from the serial port.

If you still need callbacks, for example because you need to communicate with a C API, you have two options:

- use the lower-level `create_serial_connection` function. It accepts a type that inherits `asyncio.Protocol` where you can define hooks like `data_received` (as a callback, not a coroutine), which is close to how you modeled your `Arduino` class.
- keep using the coroutine API, but use `add_done_callback` to register a callback to run when the coroutine is ready.

An example of the latter would be:

```
async def main():
    reader, writer = await serial_asyncio.connect(url="/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200)
    # Python equivalent of arduino.on('data', x):
    # 1. call reader.read() but don't await - instead, create a "future"
    # which works like a JavaScript Promise
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(reader.read(1024))
    # register a done callback when the result is available
    future.add_done_callback(future, lambda _: print(repr(future.result())))
    # go do something else - here we wait for an event just so main()
    # doesn't exit immediately and terminate our program
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

But unless you are communicating with C, I see no advantage in using this style over the normal async/await.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still confused by my previous async experience. In all previous cases, I was able to request a read of the length that matched how many bytes were waiting in the buffer. It seems with Python, for fully async (general sense, not sure when or who will send bytes first) communication I just have to read(1) in a loop?
I had been confused by https://tinkering.xyz/async-serial/ which made it look like I had to do some loop shenanigans. But, I was able to get it working with your help! This is much more simple than it appears!

Comment: @UserOneFourTwo I haven't personally used async-serial, but with general asyncio you definitely **don't** need to call `read(1)` in a loop. Something like `await reader.read(1024)` will give you as much data as possible, with 1024 being the **upper** limit. But if only 3 bytes arrive, you should get them immediately.

Comment: Thanks. After experimenting after getting it working thanks to your answer it seems that just plain old read() is fine.